# Cruncher files 9 patches in android studio

Tags: android, migration, nine-patch

I'm  migrating my project from eclipse to android studio, and I having problem with 9 patch resources, and I dont know why ? and how to overcome these errors!

What's wrong with this 9 patch image?  and why android studio doesn't accept it?

[image]

[image: spinner_selected.9.png]

[image]

this is the gradle build

```
lintOptions 
         tasks.lint.enabled false
        abortOnError = false

aaptOptions
     cruncherEnabled = false
```

and here is the exception

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>       * What went wrong:
>        Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>            [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
>       * Exception is:
>       org gradle api tasks TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

Comment: check all sides of your 9 patch image. Is any side is without marking?

Comment: @Dharak no, all sides have mark.